# Yammer javascript autocomplete returned CORS error

Tags: yammer

In my app we use Yammer's javascript autocomplete sdk.  When running my app locally, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=ma&models=user%3A5&_=1403755454828. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This seems like a new issue.  As it was working recently.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use api.yammer.com instead of www.yammer.com.  And make sure your domain is listed in JavaScript Origin on your client applications  setting page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950817/get-number-of-comments-in-yammer-feed

I have an issue in getting count of comments, can you please help?