# get number of comments in yammer feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, yammer

I am trying to get the number of comments for a yammer feed.

I used the below query

```
jQuery.getScript("https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js",function(){
console.log("script loaded");
  var commentCnt = 0;
      yam.platform.request(
          { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/open_graph_objects/"+ogID+".json"
          , method: "GET"
          , data: {"body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World."}
          , success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg) {
                        jQuery.each(msg.messages, function (index, element) {
                            commentCnt++;
                        });
                    }
                    //adds the count to the webpage.
                    jQuery("div#commentCnt").text(commentCnt);
                }
          , error: function (msg) { 
                        //console.log("message lookup failed");
            }
      });
});
```

this returned

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myApiUrl/. No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access
```

How can this be resolved? I also tried using `api.yammer.com` instead of `www.yammer.com`

Answer (score 1):

Yammer CORS error are mostly due to missing JS origins. You'd  need to define data-app-id in your code. Looks like that's missing from your snippet...

```
data-app-id="YOUR-APP-CLIENT-ID"
```

data-app-id, is the app_id of your registered app and ensure JS origin is in place.

Also, instead of using jQuery.getScript(), I'd suggest you call the script in the header section of your HTML page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="YOUR-APP-CLIENT-ID" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```